OAuth working on localhost and production in Chrome, but not Firefox / Safari
I am quite new to web development, so please bear with me!
I have deployed a React application (famtivity.fun) via Netlify with my backend hosted on Heroku (here).
Initially, Oauth for Google / Github was working fine on localhost only.
Once the app was deployed, OAuth sign-in was no longer authorizing the user upon redirect back to the profile page. However, the user was being written to the database. I stumbled upon an answer (here) on SO which had me add this line above my express session in the backend:
app.set("trust proxy", 1)
and huzzah, it was working on the Chrome browser and I assumed all was good.
Then, I noticed that sign-in was not working on mobile, and double checked that it was also not working on Firefox. The user is returned to the profile page, not signed in. They are entered into the Database (hosted on Heroku JAWSDB).
Repo links:
frontend
backend
Here is the set-up in my back-end:
const app = express();
app.use(
    cors({
        origin: process.env.CLIENT_URL,
        credentials: true,
    })
);
app.use(express.json());
app.use(helmet());

app.set("trust proxy", 1);
app.use(
    expressSession({
        secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
        resave: false,
        saveUninitialized: true,
        cookie: {
            secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production",
            sameSite: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? "none" : "lax",
        },
    })
);

// =========== Passport Config ============

// Initialize Passport middleware
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

// Initialize GitHub strategy middleware
passport.use(
    new GitHubStrategy(
        {
            clientID: process.env.GITHUB_CLIENT_ID,
            clientSecret: process.env.GITHUB_CLIENT_SECRET,
            callbackURL: process.env.GITHUB_CALLBACK_URL,
        },
        (_accessToken, _refreshToken, profile, done) => {
            console.log("GitHub profile:", profile);

            // Check for user in DB
            knex("users")
                .select("id")
                .where({ github_id: profile.id })
                .then((user) => {
                    if (user.length) {
                        // If user is found, pass user object to serialize function
                        done(null, user[0]);
                    } else {
                        // If user isn't found, create a record
                        knex("users")
                            .insert({
                                github_id: profile.id,
                                google_id: null,
                                avatar_url: profile._json.avatar_url,
                                username: profile.username,
                            })
                            .then((userId) => {
                                // Pass the user object to serialize function
                                done(null, { id: userId[0] });
                            })
                            .catch((err) => {
                                console.log("Error creating a user", err);
                            });
                    }
                })
                .catch((err) => {
                    console.log("Error fetching a user", err);
                });
        }
    )
);

// Initialize Google strategy middleware
passport.use(
    new GoogleStrategy(
        {
            clientID: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
            clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
            callbackURL: process.env.GOOGLE_CALLBACK_URL,
        },
        (_accessToken, _refreshToken, profile, done) => {
            knex("users")
                .select("id")
                .where({ google_id: profile.id })
                .then((user) => {
                    if (user.length) {
                        done(null, user[0]);
                    } else {
                        knex("users")
                            .insert({
                                google_id: profile.id,
                                github_id: null,
                                avatar_url: profile.photos[0].value,
                                username: profile.displayName,
                            })
                            .then((userId) => {
                                done(null, { id: userId[0] });
                            })
                            .catch((err) => {
                                console.log("Error creating a user", err);
                            });
                    }
                })
                .catch((err) => {
                    console.log("Error fetching a user", err);
                });
        }
    )
);

passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
    console.log("serializeUser (user object):", user);

    done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser((userId, done) => {
    console.log("deserializeUser (user id):", userId);

    // Query user information from the database for currently authenticated user
    knex("users")
        .where({ id: userId })
        .then((user) => {
            console.log("req.user:", user[0]);
            done(null, user[0]);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log("Error finding user", err);
        });
});

and the auth path :
// Github authentication routes
router.get("/github", passport.authenticate("github"));
router.get(
    "/github/callback",
    passport.authenticate("github", {
        failureRedirect: `${process.env.CLIENT_URL}/auth-fail`,
    }),
    (req, res) => {
        res.redirect(`${process.env.CLIENT_URL}/profile`);
    }
);

// Google authentication routes
router.get("/google", passport.authenticate("google", { scope: ["profile"] }));
router.get(
    "/google/callback",
    passport.authenticate("google", {
        failureRedirect: `${process.env.CLIENT_URL}/auth-fail`,
    }),
    (req, res) => {
        // Successful authentication
        res.redirect(`${process.env.CLIENT_URL}/profile`);
    }
);

// User profile endpoint that requires authentication
router.get("/profile", (req, res) => {
    // If `req.user` isn't found send back a 401 Unauthorized response
    if (req.user === undefined)
        return res.status(401).json({ message: "Unauthorized " });

    // If user is currently authenticated, send back user info
    res.status(200).json(req.user);
});

// Logout endpoint
router.get("/logout", (req, res) => {
    req.logout((error) => {
        if (error) {
            return res.status(500).json({
                message: "Server error, please try again later",
                error: error,
            });
        }
        // Redirect the user back to client-side application
        res.redirect(process.env.CLIENT_URL);
    });
});

lastly, here is the front-end request:
The profile page which checks if the user is authorized:
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
const SERVER_URL = import.meta.env.VITE_APP_SERVER_URL;
import axios from "axios";
import "./ProfilePage.scss";

const ProfilePage = ({ isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn }) => {
    const [movies, setMovies] = useState([]);
    const [isAuthenticating, setIsAuthenticating] = useState(true);

    useEffect(() => {
        authenticateUser();
    }, []);

    const [profileData, setProfileData] = useState(null);

    const authenticateUser = async () => {
        try {
            const res = await axios.get(`${SERVER_URL}/auth/profile`, {
                withCredentials: true,
            });
            setIsAuthenticating(false);
            setIsLoggedIn(true);
            console.log(res.data);
            setProfileData(res.data);
            localStorage.setItem("user_id", res.data.id);
            getWatchedList(res.data.id);
        } catch (err) {
            if (err.response && err.response.status == 401) {
                setIsAuthenticating(false);
                setIsLoggedIn(false);
            } else {
                console.log("Error authenticating", err);
            }
        }
    };

    const getWatchedList = async (id) => {
        try {
            const res = await axios.get(`${SERVER_URL}/user/${id}/watched-list`);
            const movies = res.data.sort((a, b) =>
                a.movie_name.localeCompare(b.movie_name)
            );
            setMovies(movies);
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    };

    const handleRemoveMovie = (id) => {
        try {
            axios.delete(`${SERVER_URL}/user/${id}`);
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(err);
        }
        setMovies(movies.filter((movie) => movie.id !== id));
    };

    return (
        <section className="profile-page">
            {isLoggedIn ? (
                profileData && (
                    <div className="profile-page__profile">
                        <h2 className="profile-page__header">
                            Hello, {profileData.username}
                        </h2>
                        <div className="profile-page__info">
                            <img
                                className="profile-page__avatar"
                                src={profileData.avatar_url}
                                alt={`${profileData.username} avatar`}
                            />
                        </div>
                        <div className="profile-page__watch-list">
                            <DynamicTable
                                movies={movies}
                                handleRemoveMovie={handleRemoveMovie}
                            />
                        </div>
                        <div className="profile-page__logout-wrapper">
                            <LogoutButton setIsLoggedIn={setIsLoggedIn} />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                )
            ) : (
                <div className="login-request">
                    <div className="login-request__container">
                        <h2 className="login-request__header">
                            Please login to access your profile
                        </h2>
                        <LoginButton />
                    </div>
                </div>
            )}
        </section>
    );
};

export default ProfilePage;

The login button:
import "./LoginButton.scss";

const SERVER_URL = import.meta.env.VITE_APP_SERVER_URL;

const LoginButton = () => {
    return (
        <div className="sign-on-partners">
            <a className="login-button" href={`${SERVER_URL}/auth/google`}>
                <div className="login-button__wrapper">
                    <img
                        src="/icons/google.svg"
                        alt="google logo"
                        height="32"
                        viewBox="0 0 16 16"
                        version="1.1"
                        width="32"
                    />
                    <span className="login-button__text">Login with Google</span>
                </div>
            </a>
            <a className="login-button" href={`${SERVER_URL}/auth/github`}>
                <div className="login-button__wrapper">
                    <svg height="32" viewBox="0 0 16 16" version="1.1" width="32">
                        <path
                            fillRule="evenodd"
                            d="M8 0C3.58 0 0 3.58 0 8c0 3.54 2.29 6.53 5.47 7.59.4.07.55-.17.55-.38 0-.19-.01-.82-.01-1.49-2.01.37-2.53-.49-2.69-.94-.09-.23-.48-.94-.82-1.13-.28-.15-.68-.52-.01-.53.63-.01 1.08.58 1.23.82.72 1.21 1.87.87 2.33.66.07-.52.28-.87.51-1.07-1.78-.2-3.64-.89-3.64-3.95 0-.87.31-1.59.82-2.15-.08-.2-.36-1.02.08-2.12 0 0 .67-.21 2.2.82.64-.18 1.32-.27 2-.27.68 0 1.36.09 2 .27 1.53-1.04 2.2-.82 2.2-.82.44 1.1.16 1.92.08 2.12.51.56.82 1.27.82 2.15 0 3.07-1.87 3.75-3.65 3.95.29.25.54.73.54 1.48 0 1.07-.01 1.93-.01 2.2 0 .21.15.46.55.38A8.013 8.013 0 0016 8c0-4.42-3.58-8-8-8z"
                        ></path>
                    </svg>
                    <span className="login-button__text">Login with GitHub</span>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
    );
};

export default LoginButton;

I have tried playing around with the cookie settings based on answers from other posts, and changed it to:
app.set('trust proxy', 1);
app.use(session({
    secret: "secret",
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    proxy: true,
    cookie: { 
        secure: "auto",
        sameSite: "none",
    },
}))

but this did not change the outcome
